# How to solve 'error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol' for writing a User-defined Model (FLAC) in Visual Studio 2010 C++?

Tags: c++, class, visual-studio-2010, user-defined-functions, flac

I am trying to write a User-defined Model in C++ for FLAC in Visual Studio Express 2010 C++. Initially, I am trying to run (debug and build) the built-in Strain-softening Model based on the Mohr-Coulomb criterion (Available in FLAC 8.0) by changing its name only. Once I succeed to do it, I will try to modify it as per my requirement. I am running the code in VS2010. I have already installed SDK7.1, VS2010 SP1, etc. However, I am getting the following error msg:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: i_ssoft, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
1>  modeli_ssoft.cpp
1>     Creating library C:\Program Files\Itasca\FLAC800\PluginFiles\Models\modeli_ssoft\i_ssoft\i_ssoft.lib and object C:\Program Files\Itasca\FLAC800\PluginFiles\Models\modeli_ssoft\i_ssoft\i_ssoft.exp

1>modeli_ssoft.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual class std::basic_string<wchar_t,struct std::char_traits<wchar_t>,class std::allocator<wchar_t> > __cdecl models::ConstitutiveModel::getPluginName(void)const " (?getPluginName@ConstitutiveModel@models@@UEBA?AV?$basic_string@_WU?$char_traits@_W@std@@V?$allocator@_W@2@@std@@XZ)

1>C:\Program Files\Itasca\FLAC800\PluginFiles\Models\modeli_ssoft\i_ssoft\\i_ssoft.dll : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals

========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

From the error code, it is clear that I need to add some libraries or I need to place the supporting libraries in the same project directory... which I have tried but still, I am getting the error.

Comment: You should link with the flac lib.

Comment: I have already added all the libraries available in the x64 folder in the FLAC directory. For example, I have added 'conmodel006_64.lib' which contains 'models::ConstitutiveModel::getPluginName', I believe. However, the same error remains.